# Splitting + Duplicating Row when Column has more than 6 characters

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a dataframe with 6 columns. "Tags" is supposed to only have 6 characters, but sometimes the API I am pulling from likes to mess things up. It looks like:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'user': ['Ticket ID', 'Closed Time', 'Tags'], 
                   'income': [1, 2, 3, ],
                   'Closed Time': ['08/19/20', '08/18/20', '08/17/20'],
                   'Tags': [270201, 284912, 123456789101]})
```

Currently my code is:

```
`df['Tags'].replace(to_replace='[^0-9]+', value='', inplace = True, regex = True) 

df['Tags'] = df['Tags'].astype(str).str.zfill(6)`
```

That just filters out the garbage that sometimes comes into the column. I am not sure where to start, I need something that if something in 'Tags' is longer than 6 characters, it splits Tags and duplicates the rest of the row.

Comment: could you please provide sample data ? Thanks

Comment: hyperlinked above, or do you need it written out? Sorry new here.

Comment: written out is easier for me to try on my machine, something I can copy/paste. By the way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'user': ['Ticket ID', 'Closed Time', 'Tags', 'ADDED'], 
                   'income': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                   'Closed Time': ["08/19/20", "08/18/20", "08/17/20", "01/01/01"],
                   'Tags': [270201, 284912, 123456789101, 987456321456]})

# seperate rows with long tags
df["Tags"] = df["Tags"].astype(int)
df_short_tags = df.loc[df.Tags<10**6].copy()
df_long_tags = df.loc[df.Tags>=10**6].copy()

# split tags column
df_long_tags["Tags_right"] = df_long_tags.Tags.astype(str).str[6:]
df_long_tags["Tags_left"] = df_long_tags.Tags.astype(str).str[:6]

# rearange dataframe
df_tags_split = df_long_tags.melt(id_vars=["user", "income", "Closed Time"], 
                                  value_vars=["Tags_right","Tags_left"], 
                                  value_name="Tags").drop(columns="variable")

# add to rows with valid tags
df_result = pd.concat([df_short_tags, df_tags_split]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

> ```
>      user  income Closed Time    Tags
> 0    Ticket ID       1    08/19/20  270201
> 1  Closed Time       2    08/18/20  284912
> 2         Tags       3    08/17/20  789101
> 3        ADDED       4    01/01/01  321456
> 4         Tags       3    08/17/20  123456
> 5        ADDED       4    01/01/01  987456
> ```

Comment: Thanks AMH, I get a type error, so I am guessing these is something wrong with my data:TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Comment: It probably means that your "Tags" column is of type `string`. I edited my answer to make sure it is `int`

Comment: Weird, now this: OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long

Comment: Just after loading your data, enter `df.info()`. what Dtype do you have for "Tags" ?

Comment: I believe it is an object?

Comment: Data columns (total 6 columns):
 #   Column       Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------       --------------  -----
 0   Ticket Id    136 non-null    int64
 1   Source       136 non-null    object
 2   Type         136 non-null    object
 3   Agent        136 non-null    object
 4   Closed Time  136 non-null    object
 5   Tags         134 non-null    object
dtypes: int64(1), object(5)
memory usage: 3.8+ KB

Comment: maybe try `.astype(float)` instead

Answer (score 0):

Here is the function I wrote

```
    import pandas as pd

    def separate_row(df, column_name):
        ls = []
        # convert the column to str 
        for row_dict in df.astype({column_name: str}).to_dict('records'):
            if len(row_dict[column_name]) == 6:
                ls.append(row_dict)
                continue
            for i in range(len(row_dict[column_name])//6):
                row = row_dict.copy()
                row[column_name] = row_dict[column_name][i*6:(i+1)*6]
                ls.append(row)
        return pd.DataFrame(ls).astype({column_name: df[column_name].dtype})
```

Here is the test result

```
    >>> df = pd.DataFrame({'user': ['Ticket ID', 'Closed Time', 'Tags'],
    ...                    'income': [1, 2, 3, ],
    ...                    'Closed Time': ['08/19/20', '08/18/20', '08/17/20'],
    ...                    'Tags': [270201, 284912, 123456789101]})
    >>> separate_row(df, "Tags")
              user  income Closed Time    Tags
    0    Ticket ID       1    08/19/20  270201
    1  Closed Time       2    08/18/20  284912
    2         Tags       3    08/17/20  123456
    3         Tags       3    08/17/20  789101
    >>> df = pd.DataFrame({'user': ['Ticket ID', 'Closed Time', 'Tags'],
    ...                    'income': [1, 2, 3, ],
    ...                    'Closed Time': ['08/19/20', '08/18/20', '08/17/20'],
    ...                    'Tags': [270201, 284912, 123456789101123456]})
    >>> separate_row(df, "Tags")
              user  income Closed Time    Tags
    0    Ticket ID       1    08/19/20  270201
    1  Closed Time       2    08/18/20  284912
    2         Tags       3    08/17/20  123456
    3         Tags       3    08/17/20  789101
    4         Tags       3    08/17/20  123456
```